# How to remove DNSSEC support from a domain?

Tags: bind, dnssec

A  organization has DNSSEC support for their domains. They have a BIND9 as authoritative name server running which also manages the keys. However it was decided to remove DNSSEC. Is it sufficient to remove the key material in `/var/lib/bind/pri` and to restart the server or are there steps which should be done to have it r?emoved

Answer (score 19, accepted):

No, it is not sufficient to just remove the configuration locally on an *authoritative name server*.

DNSSEC is a hierarchical system, *chain of trust* agains [DNS *cache poisoning*](https://www.howtogeek.com/161808/htg-explains-what-is-dns-cache-poisoning/).

> [DNSSEC](http://www.dnssec.net/) was designed to protect the Internet from [certain attacks](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3833), such
> as DNS cache poisoning. It is a set of extensions to DNS, which
> provide: a) origin authentication of DNS data, b) data integrity, and
> c) authenticated denial of existence.

Example of a *Chain of Trust*:

1. The zone itself is signed with the *private key* on your *primary authoritative name server*, e.g. `ns1.example.com.` has the *private key* for signing `example.com. A` with `example.com. RRSIG A`.
2. The *public key* of `example.com.` has been sent to and confirmed by the authority for `com.`, which then has it in `example.com. DS hash` and corresponding `example.com. RRSID DS`, signed with *private key* for `.com.`
3. The *public key* of `com.` has been sent to and confirmed by the *root authority*, which then has it in `com. DS hash` and corresponding `com. RRSID DS`, signed with *private root key* i.e. key for `.`, aka [Root Zone Trust Anchor](https://www.iana.org/dnssec/files):

   > The Root Key Signing Key acts as the trust anchor for DNSSEC for the
   > Domain Name System. This trust anchor is configured in DNSSEC-aware
   > resolvers to facilitate validation of DNS data.

You can get a nice visualization of any domain with [DNSViz](http://dnsviz.net/). It also detects configuration errors.

Therefore, the authority responsible of the TLD must be contacted, probably through the *registrar*, and informed that DNSSEC should be disabled for the domain. They will disable DNSSEC by removing the chaining `DS` record from their nameservers. Otherwise DNSSEC will still be enabled, causing your authoritative name server to be seen as a *rogue name server*.

Comment: Note that just removing the DS from parent zone will be enough to drop your zone to insecure status, regardless of whatever DNSSEC record you keep in it (at that moment).  That's the first step to do; you want to wait at least for TTL of the DS before actually removing the DNSSEC records.